# hash sign in facebook urls

Tags: url, facebook

I wonder, why facebook.com (hypem.com, etc.) choose a hash sign after domain to path other files. like http://www.facebook.com/#!/reqs.php#event (#!/reqs.php).

What is the reason, and they map them with javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google explains it here:
http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/web/ajaxcrawling/
http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/learn-more.html

Answer (score 0):

Mostly the hash sign is used in urls so that when you visit it, you are taken to specific location in the page without your scrolling manually.

Comment: yes, it is named anchor what you said. But in facebook' s url' s first hash sign is not like that.

Let' s examine that url:

http://www.facebook.com/#!/reqs.php#event

#event at last is what you said. but i asked first hash sign after www.facebook.com/#! that hash sign is in every url, so why did they do it like that.

Answer (score 0):

They do it like this so when, for example, you're in photos and you hit the photo Next button. This does an ajax request and gets the next photo. The problem with this is that the request doesn't change the url, and the user won't be able to Bookmark this new url!

So, they use the anchor part of the url to store these query string values.